# Orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> **Theorem:** Suppose $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $x=s+t$, for $s \in S$ and $t \in S^{⊥}$, then $s$ and $t$ are unique.
>
> **Proof:** Suppose $x = s + t$ and $x = s^\prime + t^\prime$, for some $s$, $s^\prime$, $\in S$ and some $t, t ^\prime \in S^{⊥}$.
> Then
> $$s+t=s^\prime +t^\prime$$
> $$s - s^ \prime = t^\prime - t$$
> $$s - s^\prime = 0$$
> $$\implies s = s^\prime$$
> $$t^\prime - t=0 $$
> $$\implies t = t^\prime$$

How does the proof derive $$s - s^\prime = 0$$ from $$s - s ^\prime = t^\prime - t$$
?

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that $S\cap S^⊥=0$ and $S\ni s - s'  = t - t'\in S^⊥$ so $s-s'=0$

Comment: @user52045 : this is a correct answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $S\cap S^⊥=0$ and $S\ni s-s'=t-t'\in S^⊥$ so $s-s'=0$.